# What does ' Within one month of completion of the year' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How to interpret the below sentence?

> After registration, a candidate is required to submit an annual report to the Registrar once a year within one month of completion of the year

Comment: Logically, it's ambiguous, and I'm not sure that there's a definite pragmatic leaning. I'd ask the authors what they mean (during December or during January, for a calendar year)..

Comment: My guess is this is a college/university and the year end could be in May/June timeframe.

Comment: It's a question from their English *Obscure Writing* course.  But most people would assume it means *within one month of the end of the SCHOOL year*, which usually is in the June timeframe.  (This assumes that the statement is in the context of a college or university, vs some other agency which uses a "Registrar".)

Comment: (-1 for not giving us the context.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the meaning of "year".  [Fiscal year](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fiscalyear.asp) and calendar year are rarely the same.  If Calendar year than "within one month of completion of the year" means before February 1 as the year completed on December 31.  That is, sometime in January.

Answer (score 0):

The basic meaning is clear enough: a candidate has to submit his annual report within one month from the end of the year. So if the year ends December 31, he has to submit the report by January 31.

From the fact that they don't say "by January 31", I'd guess that they're not talking about calendar years, but about some year that can have a variable start and end. For example, they may be talking about the year that ends with the anniversary of some event, such as the date a person was hired. If you were hired on April 12, then you would complete one year with the company the next April 11, and your report would be due by May 11. An employee who started on a different date would have a different year end date and thus a different report due date.